# STS JPA Tools not generating all Entities from Tables

Tags: mysql, spring, eclipse, entities, generated

I have created a few tables in my DB and a demo project in STS which I have converted to a JPA project. I then right click on it and select JPA Tools -> Generate Entities from Tables.

It works perfectly, except that it does not generate all Entities from the Tables. I have added two new tables and can see the in the Data Source Explorer, but when doing the generation, entities for those two does not get generated.

I have had this problem before, it's almost as if STS is keeping cache or something from a previous generation and now doing only that, but I am not sure where to look or how to clean it.

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working,

For those of you interested, I had to select each table one by one and generate the Entity. STS does not like it when you select all tables. Just select one and generate the entity, then repeat the process for the next one, etc, etc.